# facing issue when web scraping a page table using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, screen-scraping, cheerio

I am scraping the webpage https://www.g2a.com/rising-storm-2-vietnam-steam-cd-key-global.html

I need to get the title from the table data.

```
    var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app = express();

app.get('/scrape', function(req, res) {

    url = 'https://www.g2a.com/rising-storm-2-vietnam-steam-cd-key-global.html';

    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            var arr = [];
            var title = $('.mp-user-rating tr td').each(function(element) {
                var tableData = $(element).find('.mp-rating-popup');
                arr.push({ 'title': tableData.text() });
            });
            console.log(arr);
        }
        res.send(arr);

    });
})
app.listen('8081');

console.log('Magic happens on port 8081');

exports = module.exports = app;
```

Here arr is empty always.

[image]

The image shows the structure of the table

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

cheerio doesn't execute javascript but merely parses the html. if you need javascript to execute (e.g. when content is later loaded via ajax or when the app is a single-page-application built by the frontend), you need to use [phantomjs](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs) or hack together a solution with [electron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron) or use the newly [headless chrome with an abstraction](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface). An alternative would be to use [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom). Jsdom is great if you have control of the page you want to crawl (or server-side rendering it), but be aware that site-errors will cause your node process to crash.